# Unable to find element in GRID

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am unable to enter text in a grid cell. 
The browser is IE. I have tied many variations of syntax.
Though I have ID’s they are dynamic .

Specific Error:

```
Unable to find element
```

Here is my framework structure:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'
require 'cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<INPUT id=Grid1_txtEdit style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt; BORDER-TOP: #7f9db9 1px solid; HEIGHT: 20px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; WIDTH: 52px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #7f9db9 1px solid; POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-TOP: 4px; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; LEFT: 55px; BORDER-LEFT: #7f9db9 1px solid; Z-INDEX: 300; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 0px" _editBoxGridName="Grid1" _forceChange="false">
```

Comment: In the `style` attribute of the `<input>` tag, there's a `DISPLAY: none;` value, which means that the element will not be visible.  Is there another action that would trigger this element to be visible?

Comment: providing a bit more of the HTML (such as surrounding container elements for the one you are trying to locate), and the specific code for the line that is failing, along with more of the actual error message would be helpful in terms of other folks troubleshooting what is going wrong for you.   Try looking at the question and ask yourself "If this was another person's question, and I knew nothing about the web-page and automation code, would this be enough for me to answer their question?"

Answer (score 0):

An end user can't interact with a hidden element. WebDriver will mimic this behaviour and not try to interact with hidden elements.

Comment: I see, Thank you. When I spy on the element after enter text to the grid manually it still says display none. Looks like the only way to interact with the grid is to find and highlight the column header text and use a send_key combination. Luckily these values are not needed for validation

Comment: Are you able to do the exact same thing manually? If you are, then you should be bale to do it using WebDriver. If you can't, because the element is hidden, then you can't do it with WebDriver either.